# windows 10 "run as administrator" not starting

Tags: uac, windows-10

Under Windows 10, I'm logging as an user supposed to have local machine administrator rights. Unfortunately, when I try to launch some application by right-click-ing "Run as administrator", the application doesn't start at all.
Altough I can run it under lower privileges, some application DO start under "normal" privileges (just double click on the icon), but do not work properly (e.g.: Chrome: it starts, but cannot access the network).

Because of that, I cannot access administrative-purpose features, such as settings or thing like that.

Any idea to solve this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm unable to add an answer, but this is usually due to software breaking the right click/context menu, eg Beyond Compare.

Comment: @KERR That was it! And old install of UserInfoTip in my case, but your comment pointed me in the right direction. Uninstalled it and Run as Admin works again. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

First you should make sure that UAC is enabled and that your account is in protected admin mode. Could you open a command prompt, run: whoami /all, and share the result?

Comment: Unfortunately, any tool related to UAC does NOT start any more. I cannot see any setting. I'm administrator of that machine (as I've always been and nothing changed). Everything has always been OK, until something wrong happened to the Active Directory: my account was blocked. As soon as it was unblocked, I could log into my machine, but the problem arised and after being logged in I couldn't launch anything that requires administrator privileges

Comment: "whoami /all" would help knowing if your domain account is admin on your computer (or: net localgroup administrators). If you know the local admin's password it would also help to re-add your domain account to the administrators group if it is not anymore.

Comment: I confirm I-m administrator: running "net localgroup administrators" my name (the one that appears running "whoami") appears in the list.